# Clickable bubble popup when hovering over an event in fullCalendar V4

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, tooltip, fullcalendar-5

https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001=https%3A%2F%2Ffullcalendar.io%2Fdocs%2Fevent-tooltip-demo

Before I get into getting a clickable bubble, I'm just trying to get any bubble to work. This demo has been kicked around for a solution for my problem, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My suspicion is something is going on with the eventDidMount and tooltip piece of code. I'm not sure if I have the tooltip js imported properly. I'm also not sure if I'm calling the correct thing for info.event.extendedProps.description. What is this referencing? I've tried to reference other things like info.event.extendedProps.id, but it's like the hover isn't even being recognized. Nothing happens in the console when mousing over events.

I didn't add the fullCalendar import as I have it local, but I have added the following to my code.

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js'></script>

<script src='https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js'></script>
```

Then inside my var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {... I have added:

```
        eventDidMount: function(info) {
        var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
            title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
            placement: 'top',
            trigger: 'hover',
            container: 'body'
        });
    },
```

I've also added the CSS specified in the example to my main.css file.

Inside my calendar function I also have

```
events:  json_of_all_events,
```

Where json_of_all_events is an object that contains an array of

```
{id: 'a', resourceId: 'b', title: 'c', start:'sdate', end:'edate'}
```

and the events display fine.

The console only has warnings:

```
index.html:132 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. loadJSON @ index.html:132 (anonymous) @ index.html:150 init @ index.html:149 (anonymous) @ index.html:164

16[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See <URL> index.html:161 [Violation] 'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 192ms

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/atoms.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/polyfills.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/escape.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/playback.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/record.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Comment: `info.event.extendedProps.description. What is this referencing?`...it's referencing a custom "description" property in your event object - but only if you actually put one in there, which you haven't. You could always use the event title instead

Comment: Also, exactly what CSS did you include for the tooltip? It doesn't have its own built-in. In the tooltip demo (here's a link to it which actually works, btw: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBZpwzJ?editors=0110), you'll see there's some CSS added directly into the demo (rather than coming from a file). You'll need that CSS, or your own adaptation of it, before you'll see any tooltips on screen. Is that what you said you'd copied?